# Unable to move image using form

Tags: php, html, mysql

Below code displays form consisting of select tag with product name, when i select particular product, it allow to edit its detail. I'm able to update all text data but unable to move image file, it gives me error like undefined index: image.. Please help me solve this problem.

```html
<div class="divD">
<p>Product Model Name</p>
<?php
global $target_path1;
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("abc", $connection);     
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) 
{
  $id = $_GET['did'];
  $m1 = $_GET['model_nm'];
  $m2 = $_GET['price'];
  $m3 = $_GET['des'];
  $target_path1 = "Upload/";
  $target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['image']['name']); 
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) 
 {
  echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['image']['name'])." has been uploaded";
 }
$query = mysql_query("update product set model_nm='$m1', price='$m2',des='$m3',img1='$target_path1' where id='$id'");
}

$query = mysql_query("select * from product", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
 <?php echo "<a href='edit_products.php?update={$row['id']}'>{$row['catg_nm']}--{$row['model_nm']}</a>";
 echo "<br />";
 }?>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['update'])) {
 $update = $_GET['update'];
 $query1 = mysql_query("select * from product where id=$update");
 while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {?>
  <form class="form" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#">
  <?php echo "<h2>Update Form</h2>";
  echo "<hr/>";
  echo "<input class='input' type='hidden' name='did' value='{$row1['id']}' />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<label>" . "Model Name:" . "</label>" . "<br />";
  echo "<input class='input' type='text' name='model_nm' value='{$row1['model_nm']}' />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<label>" . "Price:" . "</label>" . "<br />";
  echo "<input class='input' type='text' name='price' value='{$row1['price']}' />";    

  echo "<br />";
  echo "<label>" . "Configuration:" . "</label>" . "<br />";
  echo "<textarea rows='20' cols='15' name='des'>{$row1['des']}";
  echo "</textarea>";
  echo "<label>" . "Images:" . "</label>" . "<br />";
  echo "<input type='file' name='image' id='image' />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<input class='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='update' />";
  echo "</form>";
  }
 }
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
 echo '<div class="form" id="form3"><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <Span>Data Updated Successfuly......!!</span></div>';
 }
?>
<?php mysql_close($connection); ?>
```

Comment: Html code to update form is in php echo :                  $query = mysql_query("select * from product", $connection);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
 <?php echo "<a href='edit_products.php?update={$row['id']}'>{$row['catg_nm']}--{$row['model_nm']}</a>";
 echo "<br />";
 }?>

Comment: I am not sure you can use GET to upload files? Have you tried with POST?

Comment: I've used POST method, it's not showing anything....neither error nor form

Comment: No you aren't = look at your "method". Though you have a lot more issues than that.

Comment: ok i'll try today again..